# Python memory behavior when nested dict retained/referenced but outer dict deleted and garbage collected

Tags: python, memory

I am trying to understand memory usage in Python in the context of nested dicts.
I have the following dict:

```py
>>> outer = {
...     'name': 'John Smith',
...     'books': [
...         {'name': 'The Goal', 'author': 'Goldratt'},
...         {'name': 'The Source', 'author': 'Michener'},
...         {'name': 'A Walk in the Woods', 'author': 'Bryson'},
...         {'name': 'Alice in Wonderland', 'author': 'Carroll'},
...     ]
... }
```

It has an address in memory:

```py
>>> hex(id(outer))
'0x2299c5ee680'
```

I assign the second book to a variable:

```py
>>> second_book = outer['books'][1]
```

If I check the memory address of `second_book` and the object within `outer`, they are the same, which makes sense to me:

```py
>>> hex(id(outer['books'][1]))
'0x2299c5d2cc0'
>>> hex(id(second_book))
'0x2299c5d2cc0'
```

I now delete the reference to `outer` and garbage-collect:

```py
>>> del outer
>>> gc.collect()
0
```

As expected, `outer` no longer exists:

```py
>>> hex(id(outer))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'outer' is not defined
```

`second_book` still exists and still references the same address in memory.  I wasn't sure this would be the case, so it's interesting to see this.

```py
>>> second_book
{'name': 'The Source', 'author': 'Michener'}
>>> hex(id(second_book))
'0x2299c5d2cc0'
```

**My question**:  Is the rest of memory, which was previously used by the entire `outer` dict, returned to the system or is it still "locked-up" because some portion of it is still referenced by `second_book`?

Comment: When you say *"memory, which was previously used by the entire outer dict"*, is your mental model that that memory would have contained the actual string objects in `outer`, and the nested dict objects (and the strings in those dicts)? It would in fact just have contained references to those objects, which lived elsewhere. As @tdelaney says, the single line of code that created `outer` actually instantiated a bunch of objects.

Comment: @slothrop my mental model is the latter, i.e. that "John Smith" is a str taking up space in memory, and that outer['name'] simply refers to this address.  Similarly, that "The Source" and "Michener" each reside in memory, and that there is some dict with keys 'name' and 'author' referencing those addresses, respectively; and a list 'books' containing references to several such dicts (which in turn have references to the actual objects).

Comment: What I wasn't clear about is whether the outermost containing object "outer" has knowledge of its parts, and if it is retained in its entirety even if only one of it's components is still referenced and the others no longer are.  From @tdelaney 's answer I understand that there is no such idea of "containership" and that the memory referenced by other objects of "outer" get returned to Python, while that of the second "books" object is retained because it's still being referenced by "second_book".

Comment: Got it, I see where you were coming from!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a collection of objects that have reference counts. When the count goes to zero - or when the garbage collector detects only circular references remain - any given object is deleted and returned to *python's* memory pool.

When you created `outer`, you created a bunch of objects that all have a single reference. `outer['books'][1]` has a single reference because of the list in which it is contained.

`second_book = outer['books'][1]` adds a reference to that object and now it has two but the others all still only have 1.

`del outer` doesn't really delete anything - it reduces reference counts. The outer list starts deleting (that is, reducing ref counts) of its contents. If an item is also a container, that delete keeps propagating down.

So, everybody gets their ref count reduced by 1. All of the objects except that one that has 2 ref counts really delete because their counts go to zero. Note that this happens during the `del` operation. You don't need the garbage collector for this. GC is needed when there are circular references. Suppose those inner dicts also had a key referencing outer. That's when you get in trouble.

In general, objects don't change their id/address. If that happened, its a new object. The augmented operations such as `+=` can create new objects. For instance

```
foo = 1000
bar = foo
foo += 1
```

The `int` object's augmented add created a new object `1001` and assigned it to `foo`. `bar` still has a reference to 1000 so it is not deleted. It may appear as though the object in `foo` changed addresses, but really a new object was created.

```
foo = [1, 2, 3]
bar = foo
foo += [4]
```

Here, the `list` object's augmented addition extended the exiting list in `foo`, so `foo` and `bar` still reference the same memory.

Comment: this is very helpful thank you.  You emphasized that memory taken up by deleted objects is returned to Python's memory pool.  Does this mean that the system (e.g. as shown by running top or a memory profiler such as memray) still sees this memory as in-use?

Comment: @teejay - yes. Python allocates system memory in larger pools and does its own allocation of objects from those pools. Since there is little chance a pool would empty, python doesn't bother trying to figure out when a pool could be returned to the system.